# How to select for all cases within a group?

Tags: sql, oracle

I’d like to get metrics on the number of cases in my table where my data fits different criteria. Currently, I have groups of 3+ that we’d like to inspect based on certain criteria.   For the time being, I’d like to get counts of the following:
The breakdown of records in a group of 3+ where CHESS = White.
The breakdown of records in a group of 3+ where DATE like ‘%16’
The breakdown of records in a group of 3+ with all combinations of chess = white and DATE like ‘%16’

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| GroupID    |    CHESS |   DATE   |
|    1       |  White   |  n16       |
|    1       | Black    |   n16      |
|    1       | Black    |   n03      |
|    2       |  White   |   n16      |
|    2       |  White   | n10        |
|    2       |    White | n11       |
|    3       |   Black  | n12      |
|    3       |   White  |    n14   |
|    3       |  Black   | n16      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

The output would be something like:

Chess count of 1 = 2

Chess count of 2 = 0

Chess count of 3 = 1

Date count of 1 = 2

Date count of 2 = 1

Date count of 3 = 0

Cases with Chess count of 1 and Date count of 1 = 1

Cases with Chess count of 2 and Date count of 2 = 0

Cases with Chess count of 3 and Date count of 3= 0

Cases with Chess count of 1 and Date of count 2 = 1

Cases with Chess count of 1 and Date of count 3 = 0

Cases with Chess count of 2 and Date of count 1 = 0

Cases with Chess count of 2 and Date of count 3= 0

Cases with Chess count of 3 and Date of count 1 = 1

Cases with Chess count of 3 and Date of count 2 = 0

Can this be done in a way that takes into account groups of any sizes, or would it have to be specific to the group size (for example would the query only work on groups of 3)?

Comment: @user7002207 You have some inconsistencies in your expected output. There are 1 and 3 whites in groups 1 and 2, respectively. There is 1 date in group 3.

Comment: I may have miswrote what is intended.  Ultimatley, I'd like to know how many of my groups contain 0 white, 1, white, 2 white etc, as well as how many groups are contain 1 white and 1 n16, 2 white and 1 n16, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like here, using `group by cube` and others:

```
with groups as (select count(case when chess = 'White' then 1 end) cnt_white,
                       count(case when tdate = 'n16' then 1 end) cnt_n16
                  from t group by groupid), 
     numbers as (select level grp from dual connect by level <= 3)
select white, n16, cnt
  from (
    select n1.grp white, n2.grp n16, count(cnt_white) cnt, grouping_id(n1.grp, n2.grp) gid
      from numbers n1 
        cross join numbers n2 
        left join groups on n1.grp = cnt_white and n2.grp = cnt_n16
      group by cube(n1.grp, n2.grp)
      having grouping_id(n1.grp, n2.grp) <> 3 )
  order by case when gid = 1 then 1 when gid = 2 then 2 when gid = 0 then 3 end, white, n16
```

<sup>**[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/WDY47544)**</sup>

Modify level `3` in subquery `numbers` to change number of groups.